# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Angular *ngIf directive couses error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-template

I get the error mentioned in question title when I click a button that schuld toggle the component.

[image]

Here is the stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-fbgbgf

Comment: Could you please trim all the unnecessary stuff from the demo?

Comment: Actually you need only the loaded page. `ngiferror`. Im afraid to break the whole stackblitz, becouse Itried it before (remove unnecessary staf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by accessing the `isFreeType` value of a description `FormGroup` by using:

```
description.get("isFreeType").value
```

instead of

```
description.value.isFreeType
```

Furthermore, the approach that you used to set the value of the `isFreeType` `FormControl` was wrong; you cant do `description.value.isFreeType.setValue`, after accesing the `value` property, you are not manipulating an `AbstractControl` anymore, just a plain value.

See the working demo in [this blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-form-bind-error)

Comment: Thanks! You used Angular `ng-container` and `ng-template`, will be there any unexpected side effect to ionic-framework with this tags?